# How to add a foreign key constraint in existing table

Tags: mysql

I am having 2 tables first is `smsusers(id,fname,lname,userid)`
'id' is primary key,
`userid` is unique key

```
address_detail(id,address,type);
```

Here I want to add `userid` of `smsusers` as foreign key to `address_detail` table.

for that i added a column to `address_detail` as `user_id`

```
ALTER TABLE address_detail add user_id INT( 20 )  default NULL;
```

Now I am adding foreign key constraint to table

```
ALTER TABLE `address_detail` add CONSTRAINT address_detail_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) 
REFERENCES smsusers ('userid') ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This step is showing following error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near ''userid') ON 
UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE' at line 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would remove the `'` on userid in the query

```
ALTER TABLE `address_detail` add CONSTRAINT address_detail_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) 
REFERENCES smsusers (userid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `REFERENCES` clause expects a column name between brackets, but you provided a string (which happens to be a column name, but this is irrelevant). Remove the quotes:

```
....
REFERENCES smsusers (userid) -- no quotes
....
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be back-quotes. Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `address_detail` ADD CONSTRAINT `address_detail_fk` 
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES smsusers (`userid`) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```